# Extracting element values during a drag/drop event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which will print the ID of the element that I have attached a droppable event to:

```
$('#myDiv').droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('ID of the item you are hovering over ' + this.id);
    }
});
```

However what I would rather do is instead print values from the actual item being dragged over the `<div>`.

```
<span class="myClass">This is the text that should be printed</span>
```

So in this case everytime I drag a `span` with a class of `myClass` over `myDiv` the actual text inside the span.

I can read the text with `$('.myClass').text()` but I do not know how to then achieve what I described above.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should able to get the target of the event by `event.target`. So to read the text, the code should be:

```
$('#myDiv').droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(event.target).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the text I'm trying to get the text from within the drag drop event handler.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I will update my answer :)

Comment: @user9993 just updated the answer. Hope it is what you need.